# Update query with join affect double the amount of table rows than exist

Tags: mysql

Recently I wrote a query for my project to update a table column with an existing value in another table using a JOIN.Please note this query follow `Mysql` syntax.

```
    UPDATE nucleus_accounts.account_address INNER JOIN nucleus_accounts.account 
    ON nucleus_accounts.account_address.account_account_unique_id = nucleus_accounts.account.account_unique_id 
    SET  nucleus_accounts.account_address.account_id_temp = nucleus_accounts.account.account_id_temp ;
```

Now I face a problem that the query update the double a number of table rows that exist.

I seriously think that it need an optimisation please help.

[image: data sample]

[image: expected output]

Comment: Can you please show us some sample data illustrating the problem.  Doubling of rows is possible via a join, but an update should not increase or decrease the number of records in a table.

Comment: @Tim thanks for your quick response.Here records are not increasing.but execution time is too high and once completed it shows 20 rows affected.Only I have 10 records each.So I think about and optimisation of query

Comment: @Tim ,sample data attached

Comment: OK now you're close...I see your problem.  We need to have some way of determining which of the two records having the same ID should be updated.  Show your expected output and tell us the logic for arriving at this.

Comment: @Tim Expected output is attached, please see the highlighted area in yellow

Comment: Does `account_address` have any sort of `address_id` column which could be used in the join?  Your current problem is that your join is not one to one.  We need to resolve this.